# Problems whit AspecJ AOP Configuration in Spring : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, aspectj

I am studying AspectJ annotation to configure AOP in Spring Framework reading this article: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/aspectj_based_aop_appoach.htm

Differently from this article I am not manually adding the jars in my project but I am using Maven.

The problem is that when I try to execute the MainApp class I obtain the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'student' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut selectAll
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.andrea.myexample.mySpringAspectJAOP.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut selectAll
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:209)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:263)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:295)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 11 more**
```

I think I have missed some dependency but I can't understand what...

This is my **pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.andrea.myexample</groupId>
<artifactId>mySpringAspectJAOP</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>mySpringAspectJAOP</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Why I have this problem? What can I do to solve?

Tnx
Andrea

**SOLUTION (solved by myself):**

I have deleted these two dependencies from my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the I have replaced it with this one:

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.8</version>
           </dependency>
```

And seems work fine :-)

Comment: from the exception trace, I don't think your problem has anything to do with maven dependency. It looks more like you missed **pointcut** definition or you just happen to forget register your **@Aspect** bean into Spring container.

Comment: the related code is in this article (it's the same example project as mine): http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/aspectj_based_aop_appoach.htm

Do you have some idea about it?

Comment: the tutorial code works fine to me. You must have missed something when you copy it over. Could you please attache your **beans.xml** as well as **Logging.java**

Comment: I have solved, I have posted my solution at the end of my original post. 

My Logging.java code is exactly the same of the articles (except for the package name, but I have replaced it in my project)

I have change my pom.xml with another dependencies and it work well

Please, can you say me what dependencies have you used for AOP in your pom.xml file?

Tnx

Comment: You can post your own solution as an answer and accept your own answer in order to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

@AndreaNobili, the following is my maven dependency. Glad you solved the problem on you own.

```
<!-- Application Context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Spring AOP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- to use AspectJ style AOP interception -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Ok, tnx...
One last litle thing...can you try to delete aspectjrt dependencies and say me if still run well?

Do you know what is the deifference between aspectjrt and aspectjweaver?

Tnx

Comment: @AndreaNobili: aspectjrt.jar is just the runtime and much, much smaller than aspectjweaver.jar, because the latter is kind of a superset containing the runtime classes plus the (load-time) weaver which is much bigger. Having said that, you only need aspectjweaver if you use LTW. For compile-time weaving it is enough to include aspectjrt.